# Java Thread Loading mulitple files from same directory

Tags: java, multithreading, file, polling

i want the strategy for loading files by multiple threads from a single directory,without accidentally loading same file by multiple threads.

***Solution:***

1. Allow each thread sequentially to collect  set of files to add in their data structure  such as arraylist and process parallel.
2. Take the filename , anyways the last 5 digits are numbers , do a `mod(last5digit,5) +1` will give `1,2,3,4,5` and respectively those file with  mod result will be processed by corresponding `Thread 1`,...`Thread 5`.

i want a solution which should not have mutual exclusion problem.kindly let me know your comments from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially any thread-safe access to a list should work. I think I would:

- put the list of files in a [BlockingQueue](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/blockingqueue_example.shtml)
- have each thread continually take the next item (file) from the queue and process it.

Answer (score 1):

Push all the files onto a `BlockingQueue` and have your pool of threads pull files off the queue.

That way, no file will be accessed concurrently and there is no need for any mutual exclusion.